# How to concatenate clips from the same video with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a long video with different scenes in it.
I want to extract and concatenate 2 scenes from the video (that do not start on an I-frame) using ffmpeg 2.1.4.

For argument, say I want 5 seconds from 01:00 and 02:00.

I can do this:

```bash
ffmpeg -ss 01:00 -i in.mkv -ss 02:00 -i in.mkv -filter_complex "
  [0:v]select='lt(t,5)'[v0];
  [0:a]aselect='lt(t,5)'[a0];
  [v0][a0][1:v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1
" -c:a libvorbis -t 10 out.mkv
```

That gives me the movie I want, but select actually forces ffmpeg to decode the entire rest of the movie.  So, how do I tell it to truncate the first movie instead of decoding it?

I would prefer to do this with an ffmpeg complex filter, if possible.  I know that I can just use `-t` to recode separate movies first, but the extra encoding step is very slow in my case and also loses a fair amount of quality for this video.

I can't seem to find a filter that truncates the length of a steam.  Are there filter nodes that correspond to the `-t` or `-ss` parameters?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## concat filter

This method is best if you need to perform additional filtering:

Use the [`trim`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#trim), [`atrim`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#atrim), [`setpts`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts), [`asetpts`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts), and [`concat`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) filters:

```bash
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex \
"[0:v]trim=60:65,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
 [0:a]atrim=60:65,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0]; \
 [0:v]trim=120:125,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];
 [0:a]atrim=120:125,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1]; \
 [v0][a0][v1][a1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[out]" \
-map "[out]" output.mkv
```

- `setpts` and `asetpts` will prevent a jerky output due to presentation timestamp issues.
- Make sure to use a recent version. See the [FFmpeg Download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links to builds for Windows, OS X, and Linux.

---

## concat demuxer

Another method is to to create the segments individually and [stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) them instead of re-encoding (to save time and quality), and join them with the [concat demuxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1).

```bash
$ ffmpeg -ss 60 -i input -t 5 -codec copy clip1.mkv
$ ffmpeg -ss 120 -i input -t 5 -codec copy clip2.mkv
$ echo "file 'clip1.mkv'" > concat.txt
$ echo "file 'clip2.mkv'" >> concat.txt
$ ffmpeg -f concat -i concat.txt -codec copy output.mkv
```

Comment: Ah, thanks.  trim is what I was missing.  However, it takes a very long time to get to the time offset I specify, as if decoding everything up to it.  Also, part of the output was missing audio.  To fix, I specified the same input multiple times with -ss, then use trim to truncate the video.  You don't need setpts in that case, since ss sets pts to 0.  That seemed to work and didn't have weird random pauses during encoding.  As for copying streams, I tried that before.  It starts at the previous I-frame, so you get a different part of the movie than the one you wanted.

Comment: Would you please answer my question it is similar to this one. http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/18247/ffmpeg-concat-demuxer-corrupted-output-freezed-video-on-some-concatenated-parts

Comment: Interestingly the `-filter_complex` works but the `concat` files doesn't - i.e. the 1st video looks fine but the quality of the 2nd is horrible.  Note, I copied these commands exactly for both (except for the input file).

Comment: How can I trim clip by frames and concatenate?

Comment: @puneet18 Are you using *concat filter* or *concat demuxer*?

Comment: @llogan can you please suggest any way to trim video by multiple frame numbers and then concatenate it

Comment: @puneet18 Answer depends on the concatenation method you intend to use. What is the concatenation method you intend to use?

Comment: @llogan I don't know about concat filter or concat demuxer. could you please suggest what the best way?

Comment: @llogan can you please check my question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63656881/how-to-trim-video-by-multiple-frame-numbers-then-concatenate-using-ffmpeg

Comment: How can I with a single command cut into separate files where some of the output files have jump cuts, that is, they're concatenations of some of the cut segments? For example, I want to with a single command (so there's only one seeking through the input file) cut out segments a, b, c, and d and create output files where the first one is concatenation of a+b and the second, c+d?

Answer (score 8):

This should work faster...

```bash
ffmpeg -ss 1:00 -t 5 -i in.mkv -ss 2:00 -t 5 -i in.mkv \
  -filter_complex "[0][1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" \ 
  out.mkv
```

There's no need to specify -t on the output.  There's no need to split the audio and video before the concat.

Comment: This uses the concat filter which will require re-encoding. This may or may not be desired by the user.